# Converting MS documents to csv files

Tags: linux, csv, ms-office

I have a bulk of MS documents and I'm using ubuntu os. I need to convert all of these documents to CSV format.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide a list of document types. Like doc, xls, ppt etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to open them with [openoffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) and then save as cvs files.

Comment: You could automate openoffice.org to do that in batch mode but your question is lacking important details to be answered. What exact formats do you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the 'xlhtml' package.
It's far from perfect but if your excel documents are simple it'll probably work.

It'll only convert Excel files. If you want to convert Word to plain text look at 'antiword'.